# how to store images referenced to many tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

i’ve got a trouble with design db for my app. i’ve got a some entity with separate tables like a company, products, categories etc and don’t understand how to store an images for those entities. if i’m add a column with images path to each tables i’ve got a trouble with duplicate code. i can’t understand how to do it like in wordpress where images store separatly of content. i can create a single table for images but how to reference each images for current entity. i’m confused and need advice how it work

Comment: have a look at Polymorphic Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships. If you have a Model (`Image`) that can point to multiple other Models (`Product`, `Category`, `Company`, etc.), then Polymorphism is the way to go 

Comment: @TimLewis Beleive me I didn't see it until now hahaha

Comment: @TimLewis its all that i need actually, thnx for answer

Answer (score 0):

You have three table if you want to store data, just create a model for each of your table  then  create a controller for your requirement for example create a controller for ProductManagerController and if you want to store image just store images in the files or folder in the root of your project or every where you want after that save name of your filename(images) in database , you can easily access to the file by filename everywhere you want .

```
$filename = $request->file("image")->store($path);
```

Comment: that's not what I asked, but thnnx for answer